# Oracle SQL: Single Index with two Columns vs index on one Column

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle12c

I have a table with a primary key and separate column.

```
create tableB(
   ID number(10)
   ,data number(10)
);
```

ID is my primary key.

I have to join 3 tables on my query and the performance issue is the B.data without an index.
B.data contains 'null' values and multiple entries on the same numbers.

```
select A.examp from tabled D
   join tableb B on D.data = B.data
   join tablec C on B.ID = C.ID
   join tablea A on C.val = A.val 
   where D.ID = :value;
```

So my question is what is the difference between an index that contains only one value like the data column

```
create index ind_tableb on tableb (data);
```

and an index that contains multiple columns like

```
create index ind_tableb on tableb (data, id);
```

**Can i get an improvement by selecting the id in the index with the data in the way i join the columns ?**

Thanks for any advise and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular query, you want the two column index version:

```
create index ind_tableb on tableb (data, id);
```

The above index, if used, would let Oracle rapidly lookup `tabled.data` values for a potential match with a `tableb.data` value.  If a match be found, then the same index would also contain the `tableb.ID` value for the next join to `tablec`.  If you just used the single column version on `tableb.data` alone, then Oracle would have to seek back to the `tableb` table to find the `ID` values.  This could hurt performance and might even cause the index to not be used.